# Enable ETW logging on an Azure Worker Role

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles, azure-cloud-services, etw

I m working on a classic Azure Worker Role and I want to enable logging using the Table storage method.

I checked "Enable diagnostics" in the worker role's properties file, and, in the "ETW Logs" tabs after clicking on the "Configure" button in the project properties, I ve added a reference to my C# class that implements the `EventSource` interface.

Here's this class:

```
sealed class SampleEventSourceWriter : EventSource
{
    public static SampleEventSourceWriter Log = new SampleEventSourceWriter();
    public void MessageMethod(string Message) { if (IsEnabled()) WriteEvent(2, Message); }
}
```

My logging storage tables are always empty.

The `IsEnabled` method is always returning `false`.

Here's my diagnostics.wadcfgx file content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DiagnosticsConfiguration xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2010/10/DiagnosticsConfiguration">
  <PublicConfig xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2010/10/DiagnosticsConfiguration">
    <WadCfg>
      <DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration overallQuotaInMB="4096">
        <DiagnosticInfrastructureLogs scheduledTransferLogLevelFilter="Error" />
        <Directories scheduledTransferPeriod="PT1M">
          <IISLogs containerName="wad-iis-logfiles" />
          <FailedRequestLogs containerName="wad-failedrequestlogs" />
        </Directories>
        <PerformanceCounters scheduledTransferPeriod="PT1M">
          <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\Memory\Available MBytes" sampleRate="PT3M" />
          <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\Web Service(_Total)\ISAPI Extension Requests/sec" sampleRate="PT3M" />
          <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\Web Service(_Total)\Bytes Total/Sec" sampleRate="PT3M" />
          <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\ASP.NET Applications(__Total__)\Requests/Sec" sampleRate="PT3M" />
          <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\ASP.NET Applications(__Total__)\Errors Total/Sec" sampleRate="PT3M" />
          <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\ASP.NET\Requests Queued" sampleRate="PT3M" />
          <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\ASP.NET\Requests Rejected" sampleRate="PT3M" />
          <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time" sampleRate="PT3M" />
        </PerformanceCounters>
        <WindowsEventLog scheduledTransferPeriod="PT1M">
          <DataSource name="Application!*" />
        </WindowsEventLog>
        <EtwProviders>
          <EtwEventSourceProviderConfiguration provider="SampleEventSourceWriter">
            <DefaultEvents />
          </EtwEventSourceProviderConfiguration>
        </EtwProviders>
        <CrashDumps>
          <CrashDumpConfiguration processName="WaIISHost.exe" />
          <CrashDumpConfiguration processName="WaWorkerHost.exe" />
          <CrashDumpConfiguration processName="w3wp.exe" />
        </CrashDumps>
        <Logs scheduledTransferPeriod="PT1M" scheduledTransferLogLevelFilter="Error" />
      </DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration>
    </WadCfg>
    <StorageAccount />
  </PublicConfig>
  <PrivateConfig xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2010/10/DiagnosticsConfiguration">
    <StorageAccount endpoint="" />
  </PrivateConfig>
  <IsEnabled>true</IsEnabled>
</DiagnosticsConfiguration>
```

Comment: Did you get this working?